# Why do i have to create another method to access a protected method from a parent class?

Tags: php

I'm currently learning OOP PHP, when i came across the following code sample

Code:

```
class MyClass
{
    //Class methods and properties go here
    public $prop1 = "I'm a class property!";

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'The class "',__CLASS__,'" was initiated!<br />';
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        echo 'The class "',__CLASS__,'" was destroyed!<br />';
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        echo "Using the toString method: ";
        return $this -> getProperty();
    }

    public function setProperty($newval)
    {
        $this -> prop1 = $newval;
    }

    protected function getProperty()
    {
        return $this -> prop1."<br />";
    }
}

class MyOtherClass extends MyClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo"A new constructor in ".__CLASS__."<br />";
    }

    public function newMethod()
    {
        echo "From a new method in ".__CLASS__."<br />";
    }

    public function callProtected()
    {
        return $this -> getProperty();
    }

EDIT:: public $prop1 = "I'm a class property!";
    public function __destruct(){
        echo 'The class "',__CLASS__,'" was destroyed!<br />';
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        echo "Using the toString method: ";
        return $this -> getProperty();
    }

    public function setProperty($newval)
    {
        $this -> prop1 = $newval;
    }

    protected function getProperty()
    {
        return $this -> prop1."<br />";
    }
}


$newobj = new MyOtherClass;
echo $newobj -> callProtected();
```

I am told that

> When a property or method is declared protected, it can only be accessed within the class itself or in descendant classes (classes that extend the class containing the protected method).

In the code above, if i were to call the getProperty method via

```
// More code....
$newobj = new MyOtherClass;

// Attempt to call a protected method
echo $newobj->getProperty();
```

i would get the error

> Fatal error: Call to protected method MyClass::getProperty() from context '' in ..........

If by extending the class MyOtherClass, it should have inherited all the methods and properties of its parent(MyClass). If so, why am i unable to simply access the getProperty method by calling it directly from MyOtherClass??

Edit: If MyOtherClass inherits the methods from it's parents then the same methods/properties are now inside it. If so, wouldn't

```
echo$newobj->getProperty()
```

be the same as

```
echo $newobj -> callProtected();
```

which is accessing it from inside the class MyOtherClass??

Comment: You are calling that method from outside the class, what is the surprise here? You can only use it as `$this->getProperty()` inside the class methods.

Comment: The docs are telling you why it doesn't work. Are you asking us why `protected` methods are not accessible from outside the class?

Comment: Why am i calling it from outside the class? Am i not creating an instance of MyOtherClass, which inherits MyClass and it's methods & properties?

Comment: @Kenneth.J You are **calling** it from outside the class.

Comment: try `echo $newobj->callProtected();`

Comment: @PeeHaa Added some additional code to hopefully clarify my question. Wouldnt calling getProtected() from MyOtherClass be accessing it from within the class since it was inherited from MyClass, and is now inside MyOtherClass?

Comment: @Kenneth.J added the explanations on access scopes, also attached something good to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic OOP access restrictions are made for encapsulation.

Public access - allows access from anywhere (outside/inside).

Protected access - allows access from inside class itself or the class that inherits(child class).

Private access - allows access only WITHIN class, not child

In additional, to deeply understand what is OOP and follow the GOOD HABBITS for OOP from the beginning - I suggest you to read [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), the five first oop principles. They are the KEY to the OOP Approach. Read and understand these.
You may also want to read [GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)) OOD Principles.
There is also a common accepted coding standards around - [PEAR Coding Standard](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php)

## Public example

```
Class A {
  public $a = "hello oop world";
  public function getA()
  {
    return $this->a;
  }
}
# call successful in any case
$a = new A;
$a->getA(); // success
echo $a->a // success due to it's access public
```

## Protected Example

```
Class A {
  public $a = "hello OOP world";
  protected $_b = "Here we test protected";
  public function getA() {
    return $this->a;
  }
}

Class B extends A {
  public function getB() {
    return $this->_b;
  }
}

# test
$a = new A; #init
$b = new B; #init
echo $a->a; // success - prints "hello oop world"
echo $a->_b; // fails with access error.
echo $a->getA(); // success print hello oop world
echo $b->getA(); // also prints hello oop world (inherited all of the parent class!)
echo $b->getB(); // return the $_b ! why? it is inherited and we made public getter in child class!
```

## Private example

```
Class A {
  private $_sharedProperty = "Sometimes Private is good!"
  public function parentGetter() {
    return $this->_sharedProperty;
  }
}

Class B {
  public childGetter() {
    return $this->_sharedProperty;
  }
}

# Now we test, as we can see, both methods trying to access shared property.
$parent = new A; #instantiate
$child = new B; #instatiate
echo $parent->_sharedProperty; // Fails with access restricted.
echo $parent->parentGetter(); // print the shared property of instance.
echo $child->_sharedProperty   // Fails also with access restricted.
echo $child->childGetter(); // FAILS ! Why? Private is not available to child!
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,

VR